# Convert full month and day name to short ones

Tags: python, datetime

I have a series of dates of this format: `'2015 08 01'` or `'2015 12 11'` and I want to convert them to this format: `'2015 8 1'` or `'2015 12 11'`. Basically, if the month and day sub-strings have a 0 at the start, that should be eliminated.

For example: The `'2015 08 01'` date string of the format (`"%Y %m %d"`), has the month number as **08** and day number as **01**. I want the resulting date to be:  `'2015 8 1'`, where the month is converted from **08** to **8** and the day from **01** to **1**.

I tried:

```
from datetime import datetime
str_date = '2015 08 01'
data_conv = datetime.strptime(str_date, "%Y%m%e")
```

but I get this error:

```
ValueError: 'e' is a bad directive in format '%Y%m%e'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the leading zeroes:

```
' '.join([x.lstrip('0') for x in str_date.split()])
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be `d`:

```
>>> data_conv = datetime.strptime(str_date, "%Y %m %d")
>>> data_conv
datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 1, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is not the solution. I want to convert the strings to another date format, but the months and days that start with 0 (eg: 01, 02..09) to be transformed to (1, 2.....9). I edited the question for a better understanding.